# The power of the axiom of choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let me consider an answer to one of my previous questions about the dramatic consequences of the unobjectionable definition of the derivative, questioned for centuries because of the use of infinitesimals.

Edit: I believe I need to clarify my question - pointwise choice of a real number seems to be a problem (without the AC) and the definition (after some definition of the reals) of a single real number seems to be subject of debate. Is then invoking the AC to choose a point $x_o$ not the same as defining this point, using for instance my obvious sequence?  This sequence is constructed after the reals are supposed to be defined and $x_0$ need therefore not be a rational number i.e. it is not intended to be part of the initial definition of reals. Edit2: I might just as well say "now I choose a number - this is also my definition of this number".

I believe now that the dramatic consequence is the possibility of a similar unobjectionable (i.e. related to objections based on the use of infinitesimals) definition of real numbers. 
Let me compare two definitions

1) The reals numbers are defined as a collection (set?) of numbers defined by all Cauchy limits, and

2) I invoke the axiom of choice and chose areal number $x_o$ and for the sequence $x_o + 1/n$ I consider the limit $x_0$ which I have managed to define (very simply).

In the second version I seem to have made a pointwise definition of an arbitrary real number, whereas in the first alternative I have merely defined a set (?). But is there really a difference of the two, taking given my arbitrary choice of $x_o$?

Comment: You don't need the axiom of choice to choose _one_ real number.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in 2). Where does that real come from if you are trying to define them?

Comment: So you have a problem with the real numbers being sets? And what exactly is a Cauchy sequence, if not a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to define the real numbers (the way you seem to be referring to) is as a set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of *rational numbers.* Given an arbitrary real $x_0,$ we almost certainly have that every single $x_0+\frac1n$ is irrational. Moreover, if you're trying to define $x_0,$ in the first place, then you *cannot define the sequence that way*.

As far as I can tell, you aren't using the Axiom of Choice at all, since you are choosing only one arbitrary element of one set.

---

**Added**: Now, if you find it objectionable for real numbers to be defined as *sets* of Cauchy rational sequences, then Choice *does* provide an alternative, by allowing us to choose *one* sequence from each equivalence class, and letting those sequences be our real numbers. One can then proceed to define operations and an order relation on this set and show that it comprises a complete ordered field (or that whatever property of the real numbers holds). The downside to this is that *you have not actually constructed the real numbers* in this fashion--that is, you haven't shown that the real numbers can exist without Choice. Moreover, the operations will necessarily be rather contrived, rather than "natural," which will potentially make proofs much more difficult than they otherwise would be.

Comment: As I mentioned to Karagila, I intended the question to mean that I use 1) first to define the reals and then 2) make the choive of a real number which I would then be allowed to choose, and in turn sucessfully define an arbitrary  number - and then ask "would the second step add anything"?

Comment: Well, you'd have found a sequence of real numbers that you could show converges to the real number $x_0.$ However, $x_0$ is *by definition* a set of Cauchy rational sequences, and so is each $x_0+\frac1n$!

Comment: @Buie: As I mention to Karagila I mainly wonder about the difference in defining all reals vs defining a particular real number (a pointwise definition of a real number) not necessaryly the same as defining the whole set.

Comment: @Jensen: My name is Asaf.

Comment: @MikaelJensen:  But you haven't given any definition for any particular real number, as far as I can tell. At least one of us is confused....

Comment: I think that is my question "can the choice itself work as a definition" and from what I hear it can´t.

Comment: @MikaelJensen: I have edited my answer to get at some potential limitations of a Choice-based definition. Take a look, and let me know if that helps.

Comment: I thank you both for your contributions. I am (now) somewhat pessimistic about this as an amateur subject. It all sounds easier at first sight that it seem to be, such as a number line represening the reals. Obviously, everything cannot be easy.

Comment: @Mikael: One can certainly use a number line to talk about the reals. The various set-theoretic constructions of the reals are all isomorphic (effectively the same) as the more familiar version. Only relatively serious set-theorists worry about explicit constructions.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, even without the axiom of choice, as long as you have power set and separation axioms (and infinity, of course) the real numbers - as defined as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences - form a set. That is an exercise in basic application of power sets, products and so on.

Now you can choose a sequence from each equivalence class, and say that these specific sequences are the real numbers. But why would you do that? It's much easier to work with the equivalence classes themselves.

Then, whenever you want to calculate something like that $x+y$ you choose *two* sequences, $x_n$ and $y_n$ from these equivalence classes and look at $x_n+y_n$ which is again a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers (something which requires proof, of course).

Your second definition, however, is circular. If you haven't defined the real numbers, what is $x_0$? If it's a rational number, fine, but if it's not a rational number, then what kind of object is it?

Comment: I've long lost hope to hear actual criticism on my posts. Again, because "U R TEH SUX11!111!!!!" is probably not going to pass as actual criticism. I hope that the downvoter "whoever" they are, actually try and read my answers.

Comment: The lack of understanding is obvious for someone who downvoted this.

Comment: @Karagila I think I should have added that 2 would imply first the assumptions of 1) and then the choices in  2), the question being whether such a naddition would make any difference

Comment: @Mikael: It seems unclear to me still. Are you suggesting to first choose a sequence for each real, and then consider the sequence defined by $x_n+\frac1n$? Why would you do that? I mean, what's the endgame here?

Comment: @Karagila: I understand (vaguely) the first step to define all real numbers as a set without the possibility of a pointwise definition of a single number. I understand (equally vaguely) that the AC would allow me to choose a number$x_o$. This number could then trivially be made to constitute a Cauchy limit = $x_o$ by my sequence. The underlying question is therefore whether the AC in itself might constitute a way to pointwise define a (or any) real number.

Comment: @Mikael: I still don't fully understand. Are you saying that you want to use the axiom of choice to choose a Cauchy sequence from each equivalence class, and decide that those are the real numbers? Nobody is stopping you. But why do you want to do that? Do you somehow expect that the addition and multiplication are now going to be pointwise? Is this going to somehow simplify something? Is this "just because you want to do it"? If the first thing, then I doubt it will happen (although I have no proof of that), if the second, then how exactly do you expect it to help? and if the last thing, yes.

Comment: @Asaf: I see now that the use of a cauchy sequence was a mistake. What I really meant was: does the choice of a real number, stemming from invoking the AC, allow me to say that this number is now defined (emanating from the debate "Definable real numbers").